# How to compare two column from two files with specific condition in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a data file `A.tsv` (field separator = `\t`) :

```
id  clade   mutation
243 40A titi,xixi,lolo
254 20B titi,toto,jiji,lala
261
267 20B lala,jiji,jojo
```

and a template file `B.tsv` (field separator = `\t`) :

```
40A titi,toto,lala
40F xaxa,jojo,huhu
40C sasa,sisi,lala
```

Based on their common column (clade), I want to compare the mutation of `A.tsv` from the template `B.tsv`. When the clade in `A.tsv`are `20B`: - If the corresponding mutation in `A.tsv` have all the mutation of `40A` in `B.tsv`, print in a new column (after the last of `A.tsv`) named `Conclusion` the clade `40A`. - It's not a problem if the line `20B` in `A.tsv` contain other mutation then those from `40A` in `B.tsv`. - If the line `20B` in `A.tsv` doesn't contain all the mutation from `40A` in `B.tsv`, don't print anything.
The result (store in a new file `C.tsv`) will look like this:

```
id  clade   mutation    Conclusion
243 40A titi,xixi,lolo  
254 20B titi,toto,jiji,lala 40A
261
267 20B lala,jiji,jojo
```

I start with that :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="\t" }
  NR==FNR{ clade[$1]=$2; next }         
  FNR==1{ print $0, "Conclusion"; next }    
  !($2 in clade){ print; next }         
  {                                     
     split($3 "," clade[$2], tmp, ",")  
     for (i in tmp)                     
       if (++num[tmp[i]] > 1)          
         ++count                      

     print $0, count                   
     delete num                      
     count=0                            
  }
' B.tsv A.tsv > C.tsv
```

but I don't know how to do the rest. Do you have an idea? Thanks

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/635949/133219) or [the one before that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635787/how-to-compare-two-column-of-two-file-and-print-the-number-of-match-with-awk) and why aren't you using either of the answers you accepted there as the starting point for this question instead of the same script you included in your previous questions since it seems extremely similar if not identical?

Comment: It's different on the approach of  handling the two files. Here is not a code on the all file but on a specific pattern on each file. That's why I can't use (because I tried) of the previous answer. Sorry if it sounds like that

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN   { FS=OFS="\t" }
     NR==FNR { if($1=="40A") { cladeB=$1; mutB=$2; "nextfile" }; next }
     FNR==1 && mutB{ $4="Conclusion"; }

{ mutbak=mutB; split($3, muts, ","); for(x in muts) gsub(muts[x], "", mutbak) }
{ print $0, (mutbak ~ /^[[:blank:],]*$/ && $2=="20B" )?cladeB:""}' fileB fileA
```

Unquote the `nextfile` statement (that for GNU *awk* then) to read the next file if you won't want continue processing the rest of the *fileB*; also note that "clade=*`40A`*" in fileB should be unique, else it would always return the last one's value.

Comment: @nstatam I know it will give wrong result if you had `titi,totojijilala,lala` for example, but to resolve that you can refer to the answers of mine in your previously asked questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It works well. I'm trying to understand your code and I have a question. If I have another clade to search (for example 40A from `A.tsv` / 40F from `B.tsv`), what part of your code had to be changed ?

Comment: @nstatam then for that you would need to define a mapping table, and that's require you open a new question and I will take a look if I saw it or you can ping me here and give the link to your question. here you only wanted for one ¬one match.

Comment: But by just re-run your script with a different example after the first one, I obtain a good result but in the next column. Do you have an idea how to change the last line in your script for the second run in order to print in the same column as the first run ? Thanks

Comment: It's exactly what I've done (`awk '...' fileB fileA.modified1`) and in result I have the data for the new assignation in the column after `Conclusion` . It' probably because in the script we do `print $0, ...` so when I re-run it , it print in the next column. How to prevents that ?